# proof that a subset of complex numbers isn't a field

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

I'm pretty sure that for $f\subset C $ where the complex numbers take the form $re^{2\pi it}$ where $r,t\in Q$ isn't a subfield of the complex numbers.  I've reduced it to  $re^{it}$ since expanding it into polar form makes clear that the $2\pi$ doesn't change anything.  I'm hoping for some direction on what field property to look at to prove that this isn't a subfield.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: start checking closure under the field operations (including division here). There is only one that fails, so proving the other three (or five, if you count the presence of 0 and 1) should give you a hint of where to look for a point of failure.

Comment: $1+i=e^{0i}+e^{2\pi i/2}=\sqrt{2}e^{2\pi i/4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $z_1 = e^{\frac{\pi}{4}i} ,z_2 = e^{\frac{-\pi}{4}i}$

$z_1, z_2 \in f\\
z_1+z_2 = \sqrt 2 \notin f$

Comment: How did you arrive at this counterexample so quickly?  experience or did you apply a process?

Comment: If $f$ is a field it must be closed under addition, and multiplication, and every non-zero element must have a multiplicative inverse.  It seemed obvious that $f$ would be closed under multiplication, and inverses didn't appear to be a problem, that left addition to tackle, so I started with the simplest case that I could think of.

Comment: Also... it should be clear f contains the roots of unity.  The roots of unity "come" in conjugate pairs.  Thus we just need a root of unity with irrational real component.  Which are easy to find.